# How to load images by url in a list view in a hashmap in fragment by .net

Tags: android, image, listview, fragment, navigation-drawer

the images in this listview are not downloaded, it is assumed that you have to download a list from the web and read it one by one, when you get to the image it brings a url that is the address of the image, but not  download and no shows it in the app, I tried picasso but I think I'm doing it.

This is created in a fragment

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest;
import com.example.negofacil.IPPublicaDSW;
import com.example.negofacil.List_items;
import com.example.negofacil.ListaEmpresa;
import com.example.negofacil.R;
import com.example.negofacil.ui.cambio_de_fragmento.Cambio_de_Fragment;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
    IPPublicaDSW clsIP = new IPPublicaDSW();
    ListView lstEmpresasprm;
    private View vi;
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/lstEmEcDsW";
    private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "lstEmEcDsW";
    private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private final String SOAP_ADDRESS = clsIP.IP_DSW() + "D-SAISWEBNEGOSERVICIOSWEB/Service.asmx";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION_MOT = "http://tempuri.org/lstEmEcDsW";
    private static final String OPERATION_NAME_MOT = "lstEmEcDsW";

    /**
     * Extraccion de la Informacion de los Mantenimientos OT
     **/
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class TareaAsyncCallWSMantenimientosOT extends AsyncTask<ArrayList, ArrayList, ArrayList> {
        @SuppressLint("WrongThread")
        @Override
        protected ArrayList doInBackground(ArrayList... params) {
            ArrayList<ListaEmpresa> lista = new ArrayList<ListaEmpresa>();
            try {
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME_MOT);
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
                propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                propertyInfo.name = "sad";
                request.addProperty(propertyInfo,"sdfsdfsdf");
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);//VER11 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);//VER11
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
                httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_MOT, envelope);
                SoapObject resSoap =(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                int nroPropiedades = resSoap.getPropertyCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < nroPropiedades; i++)
                {
                    SoapObject ic = (SoapObject)resSoap.getProperty(i);
                    lista.add(new ListaEmpresa(
                            ic.getProperty("ID_EMPRESA").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("NOM_EMPRESA").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("SIGLA_EMPRESA").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("RUC_EMPRESA").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("DIR_EMPRESA").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("DES_ESTADO").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("CONTACTO_EMPRESA").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("EMAIL_CONTACTO").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("TELEFONO_EMPRESA").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("CELULAR_EMPRESA").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("URLIMG_EMPRESA").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("DESCRIPCION_EMPRESA").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("VALOR_EMPRESA").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("DESCUENTO_EMPRESA").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("AUX1_EMPRESA").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("AUX2_EMPRESA").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("AUX3_EMPRESA").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("AUX4_EMPRESA").toString(),
                            ic.getProperty("AUX5_EMPRESA").toString()));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                String msm=e.getMessage();
            }
            String Todo="OK";
            return lista;
        }
        public void onPreExecute() {
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList result) {
            ArrayList<ListaEmpresa> lista = result;
            //creaTablaOT(result);
            List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            // Cada fila de la lista almacena el nombre
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
                hm.put("nomemp",lista.get(i).NOM_EMPRESA());
                hm.put("id",lista.get(i).ID_EMPRESA());
                hm.put("direc",lista.get(i).DIR_EMPRESA());
                hm.put("telef",lista.get(i).TELEFONO_EMPRESA());
                hm.put("celu",lista.get(i).CELULAR_EMPRESA());
                hm.put("descu",lista.get(i).DESCUENTO_EMPRESA());
                hm.put("descrip",lista.get(i).DESCRIPCION_EMPRESA());
                hm.put("imagen", lista.get(i).URLIMG_EMPRESA());
                aList.add(hm);
            }
            // Keys used in Hashmap
            String[] from = { "imagen","nomemp","descrip","id","direc","telef","celu","descu"};
            // Id. De vistas en listview_layout
            int[] to = { R.id.imageEmp,R.id.nmbEmpresas,R.id.descpemp,R.id.id_empresa,R.id.direc_emp,R.id.tel_emp,R.id.cel_emp,R.id.descuento};
            // Crear instancias de un adaptador para almacenar cada artículo
            // R.layout.listview_layout define el diseño de cada elemento
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(vi.getContext(), aList, R.layout.item, from, to);
            // Obteniendo una referencia a la vista de lista del archivo de diseño fragment.xml/
            ListView listView =(ListView) vi.findViewById(R.id.lvitems);
            // Configurando el adaptador a listView
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    if (i == i){
                        Intent intend = new Intent(getActivity(),List_items.class);
                        startActivity(intend);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    private void ConsultarMantenimientosOTSW() {
        TareaAsyncCallWSMantenimientosOT tarea = new TareaAsyncCallWSMantenimientosOT();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            tarea.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) {
                tarea.execute();
            }
        }
    }
    private void creaTablaOT(ArrayList result)
    {
        ArrayList<ListaEmpresa> lista = result;
        String MS=null;
        try {

        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MS=ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
    //Se llama cuando se crea por primera vez la actividad.//
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

// Cada fila de la lista almacena el nombre

        if(v != null){
            lstEmpresasprm= ( ListView ) v.findViewById(R.id.lvitems);
            vi=v;
            ImageView imgv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageEmp);
        }
        ConsultarMantenimientosOTSW();

        return v;
    }
}
```

this is what i try to do using picasso but it gets error in get ()

```
protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList result) {
    final ArrayList<ListaEmpresa> lista = result;
    //creaTablaOT(result);
    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    // Cada fila de la lista almacena el nombre
    for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("nomemp",lista.get(i).NOM_EMPRESA());
        hm.put("id",lista.get(i).ID_EMPRESA());
        hm.put("direc",lista.get(i).DIR_EMPRESA());
        hm.put("telef",lista.get(i).TELEFONO_EMPRESA());
        hm.put("celu",lista.get(i).CELULAR_EMPRESA());
        hm.put("descu",lista.get(i).DESCUENTO_EMPRESA());
        hm.put("descrip",lista.get(i).DESCRIPCION_EMPRESA());
        hm.put("flag",lista.get(i).DESCRIPCION_EMPRESA());
        Picasso.get().load(hm.get("flag"));
        aList.add(hm);
    }
```

this is a business class list

```
public class ListaEmpresa {


    private String ID_EMPRESA;
    private String NOM_EMPRESA;
    private String SIGLA_EMPRESA;
    private String RUC_EMPRESA;
    private String DIR_EMPRESA;
    private String DES_ESTADO;
    private String CONTACTO_EMPRESA;
    private String EMAIL_CONTACTO;
    private String TELEFONO_EMPRESA;
    private String CELULAR_EMPRESA;
    private String URLIMG_EMPRESA;
    private String DESCRIPCION_EMPRESA;
    private String VALOR_EMPRESA;
    private String DESCUENTO_EMPRESA;
    private String AUX1_EMPRESA;
    private String AUX2_EMPRESA;
    private String AUX3_EMPRESA;
    private String AUX4_EMPRESA;
    private String AUX5_EMPRESA;

    public ListaEmpresa()
    {
    }

    public ListaEmpresa(String ID_EMPRESA, String NOM_EMPRESA, String SIGLA_EMPRESA, String RUC_EMPRESA, String DIR_EMPRESA, String DES_ESTADO,
                        String CONTACTO_EMPRESA, String EMAIL_CONTACTO, String TELEFONO_EMPRESA, String CELULAR_EMPRESA, String URLIMG_EMPRESA,
                        String DESCRIPCION_EMPRESA, String VALOR_EMPRESA, String DESCUENTO_EMPRESA, String AUX1_EMPRESA, String AUX2_EMPRESA,
                        String AUX3_EMPRESA, String AUX4_EMPRESA, String AUX5_EMPRESA)
    {
        this.ID_EMPRESA = ID_EMPRESA;
        this.NOM_EMPRESA = NOM_EMPRESA;
        this.SIGLA_EMPRESA = SIGLA_EMPRESA;
        this.RUC_EMPRESA = RUC_EMPRESA;
        this.DIR_EMPRESA = DIR_EMPRESA;
        this.DES_ESTADO = DES_ESTADO;
        this.CONTACTO_EMPRESA = CONTACTO_EMPRESA;
        this.EMAIL_CONTACTO = EMAIL_CONTACTO;
        this.TELEFONO_EMPRESA = TELEFONO_EMPRESA;
        this.CELULAR_EMPRESA = CELULAR_EMPRESA;
        this.URLIMG_EMPRESA = URLIMG_EMPRESA;
        this.DESCRIPCION_EMPRESA = DESCRIPCION_EMPRESA;
        this.VALOR_EMPRESA = VALOR_EMPRESA;
        this.DESCUENTO_EMPRESA = DESCUENTO_EMPRESA;
        this.AUX1_EMPRESA = AUX1_EMPRESA;
        this.AUX2_EMPRESA = AUX2_EMPRESA;
        this.AUX3_EMPRESA = AUX3_EMPRESA;
        this.AUX4_EMPRESA = AUX4_EMPRESA;
        this.AUX5_EMPRESA = AUX5_EMPRESA;
    }

    public String ID_EMPRESA() {
        return ID_EMPRESA;
    }
    public String NOM_EMPRESA() {
        return NOM_EMPRESA;
    }
    public String SIGLA_EMPRESA() {
        return SIGLA_EMPRESA;
    }
    public String RUC_EMPRESA() {
        return RUC_EMPRESA;
    }
    public String DIR_EMPRESA() {
        return DIR_EMPRESA;
    }
    public String DES_ESTADO() {
        return DES_ESTADO;
    }
    public String CONTACTO_EMPRESA() {
        return CONTACTO_EMPRESA;
    }
    public String EMAIL_CONTACTO() {
        return EMAIL_CONTACTO;
    }
    public String TELEFONO_EMPRESA() {
        return TELEFONO_EMPRESA;
    }
    public String CELULAR_EMPRESA() {
        return CELULAR_EMPRESA;
    }
    public String URLIMG_EMPRESA() {
        return URLIMG_EMPRESA;
    }
    public String DESCRIPCION_EMPRESA() {
        return DESCRIPCION_EMPRESA;
    }
    public String VALOR_EMPRESA() {
        return VALOR_EMPRESA;
    }
    public String DESCUENTO_EMPRESA() {
        return DESCUENTO_EMPRESA;
    }
    public String AUX1_EMPRESA() {
        return AUX1_EMPRESA;
    }
    public String AUX2_EMPRESA() {
        return AUX2_EMPRESA;
    }
    public String AUX3_EMPRESA() {
        return AUX3_EMPRESA;
    }
    public String AUX4_EMPRESA() {
        return AUX4_EMPRESA;
    }
    public String AUX5_EMPRESA() {
        return AUX5_EMPRESA;
    }

}
```

everything works correctly the names are shown and everything in general, but the image is not shown

[image]

sorry for the censorship but they are orders, the image of each item must go in the yellow part but the image does not load

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that you get an error in the get() method, it would be easier if you showed it :)

I assume that the link which is here *hm.get("flag")* to the image is correct , so to load the image you must change:

```
Picasso.get().load(hm.get("flag"))
```

To:

```
Picasso().get().load(hm.get("flag")).into(element_you_are loading_the_image_into)
```

EDIT:
On picasso website they use code like this:

```
Picasso.get().load("some_url").into(some_image_view)
```

If you still got error, try to use this link to image "http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png"(picasso doc use it) then you will be sure that not your link is the problem

*A replacement for picasso can still be a glide I have never had problems with it

Comment: the error I get (Picasso. <get ()>) is here, I don't know if maybe there is another way to load the image but I only know Picasso

Comment: Are you sure that the link to the image is direct, and its valid?

Comment: how can i apply the glide on this?

Comment: https://github.com/bumptech/glide  there you can find all Information you need. There are also plenty of guides on the internet

Comment: excuse me could you help me, like moving to another fragment, when select an item from the listview,what I have is when I select an item, it takes me to a separate activity and the (navigation drawen) disappears .
try to put the class name of the fragment, but when i select an item from the listview the application closes

Comment: u should create new question on Stack :)